# Riding Loveland Pass, Colorado

Tags: touring, bikepacking

I'll soon be attempting Loveland Pass west of Denver unsupported and would like to hear of any experiences and/or recommendations from others who have done it or another high mountain pass in the Rockies (or elsewhere). Particularly regarding how much food & water I'll need to carry over the top, how cold it will get at night in July (no rain expected).  It will be my first attempt.  I ride an old Scott NRS 3 with bikepacking bags.

Comment: Why do you expect no rain? Thunderstorms are very common in the mountains: [Accuweather's forecast for Keystone, CO](https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/keystone-co/80435/weather-forecast/2201315), which is on the pass, suggests that thunderstorms are somewhere between likely and possible every day in the next two weeks. Also, I really don't understand why you're asking us about the weather, rather than looking at any of the many weather forecasting sites. Honestly, it sounds like you're very under-prepared for this ride. It's good that you're looking for advice but is this really a good idea?

Comment: Er, actually, Keystone is about 3000ft below the summit of the pass so the temperatures there probably aren't very relevant. But you can probably find forecasts for the various ski resorts up there. Presumably, though, you don't want to spend the night anywhere near the summit: Keystone is only ten miles away.

Comment: https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lon=-105.86491&lat=39.66725

Comment: You can look up how much temperature drops on average vs increase in altitude, it depends on day/night and conditions.

Comment: 'Survey' type questions i.e, asking for other people's experiences don't work very well on this site, as it's oriented more around questions with objective answers. You could re-write your question to ask what you need to deal with or take into account on a multi-day high altitude ride in the Rockies during summer.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. You are correct in that I was under prepared when I posted my question. I have since done my research and feel ready to go.